# Counting the duplicate keys of 1 array and update the matching value of the second array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to count the duplicate keys from array `$new_result_months`, remove them and update the value of `$new_result_users` with the matching key. if I would do an `array_combine` every key should match the value. I really tried but did not managed to think of a version.

```
$new_result_months = array(  
                        'Dec 2013',
                        'Jan 2014',
                        'Feb 2014',
                        'Mar 2014',
                        'Apr 2014',
                        'May 2014',
                        'Jun 2014',
                        'Jul 2014',
                        'Aug 2014',
                        'Sep 2014',
                        'Oct 2014', 
                        'Oct 2014', // remove one duplicate key and keep unique one
                        'Nov 2014', 
                        'Nov 2014', // remove one duplicate key and keep unique one
                        'Nov 2014', // remove one duplicate key and keep unique one
                        'Dec 2014'
                    );
$new_result_users = array(
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          1,
                          0,
                          1,
                          1,
                          0
                    );
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
$new_result_months = array(  
                        'Dec 2013',
                        'Jan 2014',
                        'Feb 2014',
                        'Mar 2014',
                        'Apr 2014',
                        'May 2014',
                        'Jun 2014',
                        'Jul 2014',
                        'Aug 2014',
                        'Sep 2014',
                        'Oct 2014',
                        'Nov 2014',
                        'Dec 2014'
                    );

$new_result_users = array(
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          1,  // needs to match with month oct 2014 and update it to 1
                          2, // needs to match with month nov 2014 and update it to 2
                          0
                    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you count the duplicated values with `array_count_values`:

```
$aux = array_count_values($new_result_months);
```

The new created array `$aux` will have this values:

```
['Dec 2013'] => 1
['Jan 2014'] => 1
['Feb 2014'] => 1
['Mar 2014'] => 1
['Apr 2014'] => 1
['May 2014'] => 1
['Jun 2014'] => 1
['Jul 2014'] => 1
['Aug 2014'] => 1
['Sep 2014'] => 1
['Oct 2014'] => 2 
['Nov 2014'] => 3
['Dec 2014'] => 1
```

Then, with a foreach loop, you can create the new arrays that you want:

```
foreach($aux as $key => $value) {
    $new_result_months[] = $key;
    $new_result_users[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: ok, but everything should be -1 like DEC 2013 should be 0 and Oct 2014 should be 1 and Nov 2014 should be 2

Comment: added `$new_result_users[] = $value - 1;` Can't believe I missed `array_count_values`

Comment: @user3467855 PHP is a built-in nightmare. One is always missing things with it.